# When I attempt to use a recordset in Access VBA to fill a text field in a table it removes all the line breaks from the data

Tags: ms-access

I have tried a number a methods to introduce the hard return including chr(10) & chr(13), vbnewline, vbcr, vblf, vblfcr

This works fine if I am inserting into a textbox on the form, but not when I am using a recordset to write data directly to the table

Here is a sample of the string I am trying to write including the hard returns:

---

IFC
NON-INTERCHANGE STATIONS MOUNT DENNIS

PARTIAL FLOOR PLAN CONCOURSE LEVEL

RTI-ECL801_A2004_Rev06

---

Once written to the table the data looks like this with hard returns not shown:

---

IFC NON-INTERCHANGE STATIONS MOUNT DENNIS PARTIAL FLOOR PLAN CONCOURSE LEVEL RTI-ECL801_A2004_Rev06

---

after a great deal of experimentation, it looks like the characters for the hard return are embedded into the text, but it does not display correctly in the table.
When I cut and paste the text into another application (excel or notepad for instance) it shows up with the hard returns shown, but a form in access does not show with the hard returns.
I'm baffled, and have spent the bulk of today trying to figure out what should be a simple operation.
Here are some excerpts from the code

```
'set sheet in Excel
xl.Worksheets("Drawings").Activate
...
'open recordset 
rstData.Open "Drawings", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, 
adLockOptimistic
...
'write data from Excel cell into table field
rstData.AddNew
rstData.Fields("Drawing") = PreserveHardReturns(Trim(xl.Range(drawingCol & currRow)))
```

```
Public Function PreserveHardReturns(inputString As String) As String
    Dim stringParts() As String
    Dim i As Long

    stringParts = Split(inputString, vbCrLf)

    i = LBound(stringParts)
    PreserveHardReturns = ""

    While i < UBound(stringParts) + 1
        If i = UBound(stringParts) Then
            PreserveHardReturns = PreserveHardReturns & _
                        stringParts(i)
        Else
            PreserveHardReturns = PreserveHardReturns & _
                        stringParts(i) & vbNewLine
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend

End Function
```

Comment: Edit question to post code. Probably won't help your issue but Chr(13) must precede Chr(10).

Comment: good tip, but that won't help me.  thx

Comment: I added the function I was using earlier at the end of my question.  I tried all of the code I know of to force the new line.  VB newline works correctly when writing the string into a textbox on a form.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this forum.  I am a very experienced VBA programmer though in Access and this is baffling me.  I did add the code to the question.

Comment: I added the function call to the example in the question

Comment: Is your textbox set to multi-line?

Comment: Should provide fully reproducible and executable code. That includes the Excel setup and looping structure. However, I did a simple test of adding a new record via recordset  with concatenated vbCrLf and value in table displays as multiline. Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your test code with me?

Comment: Nick,  I'm writing via a recordset operation to the table directly.  I do not have a form with a text box on it.  I did run a test and set up a dummy form and I am able to write the string into a text box and get the correct behavior.

Comment: If the data is coming from Excel I think it uses a singular CR or LF character for new lines.  Perhaps just use the replace function to replace a CR and a LF character to CRLF?

Comment: thanks, that is a helpful suggestion

Comment: tried a replace for vbcr and one for vblf with no improvement

Answer (score 0):

I created a worksheet with multi-line cells using Alt+Enter.

This simple code preserves multi-line structure in Access table when importing Excel data via recordset AddNew method.

```
Sub test()
Dim xl As Excel.Application, wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Owner\June\MyStuff\Condos.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Condos")
rs.AddNew
rs!Unit = Replace(ws.Range("D2"), Chr(10), vbCrLf)
rs.Update
wb.Close False
xl.Quit
End Sub
```

So in your code, consider:

```
rstData.Fields("Drawing") = Replace(Trim(xl.Range(drawingCol & currRow)), Chr(10), vbCrLf)
```

Comment: thanks all, I figured it out.  Excel uses vblf, I replaced that with vbnewline and it works!